# How to unbind jQuery touchwipe?

Tags: jquery, ios, unbind

I am able to get [touchwipe](http://www.netcu.de/jquery-touchwipe-iphone-ipad-library) running when my page enters a kind of fullscreen mode, but how can I unbind its events when I leave it?

I tried...

```
$(document).unbind();
$(document).unbind('touchmove touchstart');
$(document).off();
$(document).off('touchmove touchstart');
$(document).touchwipe({
    wipeLeft:function(){},
    wipeRight:function(){},
    wipeUp:function(){},
    wipeDown:function(){}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using touchwipe on something other than the document itself, something which gets removed and redisplayed. So, no unbind but a working touchwipe.